# How to prove the following using Cauchy Schwarz inequality.

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are non-negative numbers, then prove the following by using Cauchy Schwarz inequality.  $$\sqrt{3a^2+ab}+ \sqrt{3b^2+bc}+ \sqrt{3c^2+ca} \leq 2(a+b+c)$$
How to think for this?

Comment: Do we have $a,b,c \ge 0$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\sqrt{3a^2+ab} = \left(\sqrt{a}\right)\left(\sqrt{3a+b}\right)$. Can you figure out how to apply Cauchy-Schwarz from here?

Comment: @GAVD The problem stipulates that $a,b,c\geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

For non-negative variables by C-S
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{3a^2+ab}=\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{a(3a+b)}\leq\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}a\sum_{cyc}(3a+b)}=2(a+b+c).$$

Also, AM-GM works:
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{3a^2+ab}=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{cyc}\left(2\sqrt{4a(3a+b)}\right)\leq\frac{1}{4}\sum_{cyc}(4a+3a+b)=2(a+b+c).$$